# Embedd Matplotlib chart in a PyQt GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have written the following script which is creating an empty GUI with a button that calls a Matplotlib chart:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SmallGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SmallGUI,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(1010,800,1010,800)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample')

        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background,QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(palette)

        #Chart button
        self.MyButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.MyButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(88,65,110,20))
        self.MyButton.setText('Create chart')
        ###############

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.MyButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(bool)"),self.makeChart)

        self.show()

    def makeChart(self):
        plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
        plt.ylabel('some numbers')
        plt.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sampleForm = SmallGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am wondering if there is any way to embedd the chart into the GUI. In other words, is it possible to make the chart showing attached to the user interface rather than popping up a new TK window?

Comment: yes, see http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html

Comment: @tcaswell great. Could you please write your comment as an answer so I will mark it and close the question?

Comment: no, link only answers are frowned on.

Comment: Ok never mind, I'll try to adjust my code and re-paste it here self-answering my question ;)

Comment: I have made such an application a while back:
https://github.com/tschm/PandasMonitor However, these days I would look into Bokeh...